# Guardar nome do ficheiro com espaços em branco html/php

Tags: php, html, download

Tenho o seguinte botão que vai para um ficheiro:

```
<a href="download_file.php?file=ficheiro_xls/BD%20Fugas%20Gespost.xls">Download XLS</a>
```

No ficheiro download_file.php tenho o seguinte:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

$file = $_GET["file"];
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));   
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
flush(); // this doesn't really matter.
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
} 
fclose($fp); 

?>
```

Funciona tudo correctamente, o ficheiro é descarregado. Mas o objectivo é o ficheiro ficar guardado com o seguinte nome "**BD Fugas Gespost.xls**" e está a ficar guardado como "**ficheiro_xls%2FBD+Fugas+Gespost.xls**". Já experimentei como está em cima usar o `%20` para substituir o espaço, mas não resulta

Comment: acho que o seu problema esta na linha que você fala: `file=ficheiro_xls/BD%20Fugas%20Gespost.xls` e depois lê: `$file = $_GET["file"];`. O problema não está no PHP, mas sim na instrução que você passa à ele. Veja se é necessário constar esse `ficheiro_xml/`.

Comment: @FredDutra, não é necessário constar o ficheiro_xml/

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, decida qual é o `Content-Type` desejado, você tem 3 headers com `Content-Type`, e deve ter um só.

Como o nome do seu arquivo já está codificado, você pode tirar o urlencode do `$file`:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $file );
```

entretanto, como tem nome de pasta no `$file`, talvez seja o caso de pegar só o nome do arquivo:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename( $file ) );
```

### Alternativamente:

Eventualmente você poderia fazer diferente, sem o encode no link:

```
<a href="download_file.php?file=ficheiro_xls/BD FugasGespost.xls">Download XLS</a>
```

mantendo o urlencode no *header*:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));
```

e talvez alterando a abertura do `$file`, mas aí depende de como está o nome verdadeiro do arquivo no filesystem:

```
$fp = fopen( urldecode( $file ), 'r' );
```

Comment: desse modo o ficheiro não é gravado com extensão

Comment: @pc_oc uma coisa que pode estar atrapalhando é a barra

Comment: Editei, experimente a solução com basename().

Comment: @Bacco, acho que o problema é que ele passa `file=ficheiro_xls/BD%20Fugas%20Gespost.xls` e depois lê: `$file = $_GET["file"];`. O problema não está no PHP, mas sim na instrução que ele passa ao PHP.

Comment: @FredDutra É capaz. Mais ou menos o que eu sugeri na 2a opção, fazer sem encoding prévio.

Comment: @Bacco, com o basename ele tenta gravar apenas o ficheiro com o nome "BD", ou seja, chega ao espaço e não via buscar o resto do nome do ficheiro

Comment: @pc_oc você não misturou as 2 soluções né? Cuidado que na resposta eu sugeri ou tirar o encode, ou mudar o URL. Não faça as duas coisas simultaneamente. Se for o caso, edito a resposta para separar melhor as idéias. Que OS vc está usando?

Comment: @Bacco estou a usar windows8.1. Usando a alternativa, ele está a substituir o " " por "+".

Comment: + e %20 são a mesma coisa em URLencode, é normal isso. Se chegou até aí tudo bem. Deu problema pra abrir o arquivo? Acrescentei o urldecode no $file. Se puder, teste com `basename( urldecode( $file ) )` no header também.

Comment: tem tambem o rawurlencode e o rawurldecode que são parecidos com urlencode e urldecode, porém tratam o "+" diferentemente.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o `str_replace` do PHP.

`str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )`

Primeiro você fará o seguinte: 
`str_replace("ficheiro_xls%2F", "", $variavel);`

Dessa  forma você tira esses caracteres iniciais do nome.

Depois repita a operação substituindo o `+` por , assim: `str_replace("+", " ", $variavel);`

**Documentação**: [Str_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php).

**Dica**: não acho uma boa usar reg. exp. porque você terá que fazer dois ou três passos para alcançar o mesmo resultado que você terá com o srt_replace.

Comment: já tentei assim e o ficheiro é guardado com o mesmo nome. penso que o problema pode estar em alguma configuração do download_file.php

Answer (score 0):

Cara, tenta isso:

```
        <?php
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

        #Tente usar este aqui.
        #Em um index terá o nome do arquivo completo, como veio do GET, mas sem barra ao contrario
        #E no outro, um outro array onde conterá, a(s) pasta(s) do arquivo, e no ultimo index o nome do arquivo
        $arrFile = array(
          str_replace("\\","/", $_GET["file"]),
          explode("/",str_replace("\\","/", $_GET["file"]))
          );


        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='" . urldecode(end($arrFile[1]))."'";
 #Aqui em cima, você deveria usar o URLDECODE, pois a url já veio com os caracteres especiais, não precisaria "encodar" denovo   
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Type: application/download");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($arrFile[0])); #Aqui você usa o caminho completo do arquivo
        flush(); // this doesn't really matter.
        $fp = fopen($arrFile[0], "r"); #Aqui você usa o caminho completo do arquivo
        while (!feof($fp))
        {
            echo fread($fp, 65536);
            flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
        } 
        fclose($fp); 

        ?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Com este código o download não começa, ou seja, sou reencaminhado para a página download_file.php e o download não começa